How do I make my program do something when a file is opened with it in c++
I want to be able to detect when a file is opened with my program like when you double click a .docx file word opens the file automatically.
I haven't tried yet because this is the only function of this program is to detect when a file ending in the extension .prop was opened with my program

Please remove tag `google-sheet.

I assume you are talking about Microsoft Windows. It's not your program that decides what happens when you double-click on a file with specific extension (like.docx), it's Windows. For example, in Windows 11, go to Start, Settings, Apps, Default apps, and there under "Set a default for a file type or link type", type ".docx" and press Enter. You'll usually see Microsoft Word as the assigned program, but you can tap there and set some other app as the default. The same would be with ".prop" or any other file extension. If there is no default app assigned yet, tap on "Choose a default".

Assuming you are referring to Windows, the simplest solution is to register your file extension in the Registry, and tell Windows exactly what you want to happen when a user double-clicks on a file with your extension.
The most common action is to run your app with the full path of the clicked file as a command line parameter. You would then code your app to look for that input parameter at startup, such as in the argv array of a console app's main() function, or via GetCommandLineW() and CommandLineToArgvW() in a GUI app.
There are other actions available, such as invoking a DDE server, or a COM server.
Microsoft has many many pages of documentation on this subject, such as:
How File Associations Work
File Types
File Type Handlers
Application Registration
Implementing a Custom File Format
How to Register a File Type for a New Application
Just to name a few...
